# How JS engine treat variable declaration in Condition block?

Tags: javascript

All:

I have one question about variable declaration, if I declare a variable in a if block, when JS engine meet that line, how does the engine know how to set that variable?

I know this is terrible way to declare variable, but just curious how JS engine works with it:

```
if( trueSituation ){
    var a_variable = true;
}else {
    var another_variable = false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "how do it know how to set that variable?" did you mean "how does it know how to set that variable?"

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia  Sorry, my typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript has a term called 'variable hoisting'.  When your code actually executes, all the `var`s get pulled to the top of the enclosing function:

```
function foo() {
    var a_variable;
    var another_variable;
    if( trueSituation ) {
         a_variable = true;
    }else {
         another_variable = false;
    }
}
```

Prior to the `if/else`, you can `console.log(a_variable)` as the special value `undefined`.

As a side note, ES6 contains a construct called `let` that allows more traditional block scoping, however I believe it still hoists the variable to the top of the block.

Comment: Thanks for explain. I kinda want to know what level will that varibale to be hoisted? Will it reach the first function scope or global if no function scope

Comment: @Kuan: `var` hoists to function scope, `let` hoists to block scope

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I wonder if there is no function defined AND there are multiple <script> tags, will it just hoisted to the scope of that <script> tag block or available across all <script> tags?

Comment: @Kuan if there is no enclosing function, yes it will hit global.  One reason a lot of libraries wrap in IIFEs.

Comment: @Kuan script tags all share the same top-level global scope.  That's why when you include jQuery as a script, it is available on all other scripts as a $/jQuery reference.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, variable declarations are hoisted to the top of their containing scope.

So in your example, this:

```
if( trueSituation ){
  var a_variable = true;
} else {
  var another_variable = false;
}
```

… becomes this:

```
var a_variable, another_variable;

if( trueSituation ){
  a_variable = true;
} else {
  another_variable = false;
}
```

Both variables end up declared, but only one becomes defined based on the truthiness of `trueSituation`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I kinda want to know what level will that varibale to be hoisted? Will it reach the first function scope or global if no function scope

Comment: It will be in the global scope if outside a function, or within the scope of its immediate function.

Comment: thanks  I wonder if there is no function defined AND there are multiple <script> tags, will it just hoisted to the scope of that <script> tag block or available across all <script> tags?

Comment: Global variables are accessible within all `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

Variable declarations are hoisted, which means that all declarations in a code block are done before the code is executed. The code works just like:

```
var a_variable, another_variable;

if( trueSituation ){
  a_variable = true;
} else {
  another_variable = false;
}
```

Note that all the variables in the block are declared every time, even if they won't be used that time the code is executed.

You can even put the declaration after the code that uses the variable, and in code that will never actually be executed:

```
if( trueSituation ){
  a_variable = true;
} else {
  another_variable = false;
}

if (false) {
  var a_variable, another_variable;
}
```

Comment: THanks for this example, very interesting, so this means even that declaration never get called, I still declare those two variables as local variable if this code inside a function?

Comment: @Kuan: Yes. Note that a declaration with assignment like `var a_variable = true` is really a declaration `var a_variable;` and an assignment `a_varaible = true`. The declaration is hoised, but the assignment remains in the code that is executed.